# How to make a tk gui register movement on it even when its underneath other windows

Tags: python, events, tkinter

So say I have a tkinter program get the coords of the mouse when...

1. The mouse is in the gui
2. The mouse is in the visible part of the gui

How can I make it so it regesters mouse coords **even when** these dont apply?

Source Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
hog = open("lols.txt", "a")
def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    x *= 19
    y *= 20
    hog.write("%s %s" % (x, y))
root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
root.mainloop()
hog.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter has no ability to do this. It can only handle events when it is in the foreground. For you to do this would require some external platform-specific library or program.